# Debugging scripts, what is the difference between -x to set -euxo pipefail?

Tags: shell-script, debugging

The main way I know to debug scripts is adding `-x` to the shabang (`#!/bin/bash -x`).

I recently came across a new way, adding `set -euxo pipefail` right under the shabang, as in:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euxo pipefail
```

What is the main difference between the two ways of debugging? Are there times you would prefer one above the other?

As a freshman, [after reading here](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=set%20-euxo%20pipefail), I couldn't extract such conclusion.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First, I'm afraid that explanation of `-o` option served by http://explainshell.com is not entirely correct.

Given that `set` is a bulit-in
command, we can see its documentation with `help` by executing `help set`:

```
  -o option-name
      Set the variable corresponding to option-name:
          allexport    same as -a
          braceexpand  same as -B
          emacs        use an emacs-style line editing interface
          errexit      same as -e
          errtrace     same as -E
          functrace    same as -T
          hashall      same as -h
          histexpand   same as -H
          history      enable command history
          ignoreeof    the shell will not exit upon reading EOF
          interactive-comments
                       allow comments to appear in interactive commands
          keyword      same as -k
          monitor      same as -m
          noclobber    same as -C
          noexec       same as -n
          noglob       same as -f
          nolog        currently accepted but ignored
          notify       same as -b
          nounset      same as -u
          onecmd       same as -t
          physical     same as -P
          pipefail     the return value of a pipeline is the status of
                       the last command to exit with a non-zero status,
                       or zero if no command exited with a non-zero status
          posix        change the behavior of bash where the default
                       operation differs from the Posix standard to
                       match the standard
          privileged   same as -p
          verbose      same as -v
          vi           use a vi-style line editing interface
          xtrace       same as -x
```

As you can see `-o pipefail` means:

> the return value of a pipeline is the status of the last command to
>   exit with a non-zero status, or zero if no command exited with a
>   non-zero status

**But it doesn't say:** `Write the current settings of the options to standard output in an unspecified format.`

Now, `-x` is used for debugging as you already know it and `-e` will
stop executing after the first error in the script. Consider a script
like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euxo pipefail
echo hi
non-existent-command
echo bye
```

The `echo bye` line will never be executed when `-e` is used because
`non-existent-command` does not return 0:

```
+ echo hi
hi
+ non-existent-command
./setx.sh: line 5: non-existent-command: command not found
```

Without `-e` the last line would be printed because even though an
error happened we didn't tell `Bash` to automatically exit:

```
+ echo hi
hi
+ non-existent-command
./setx.sh: line 5: non-existent-command: command not found
+ echo bye
bye
```

`set -e` is often put at the top of the script to make sure that the
script will be stopped when the first error is encountered - for
example, if downloading a file failed it doesn't make sense to extract
it.

Comment: I read the answer but I'm not sure I get this: What is the syntax you recommend using (I believe it's slightly different, like this `set -uxo pipefail`).

Comment: If you mean `set -e` it just will cause will cause script terminate on error. In your example it's only one of many options together with `-uxo pipefail`.

Comment: I meant to say I'm not sure if you suggest me to use or not using the `e` argument.

Comment: It depends on your requirements. It's not set by default so it's up to the author. If you're sure that all commands used in the script would always return `0` on success and non-zero on failure then `-e` is useful but as everything else it should be used with caution.

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure this way, so I'd better remove it.

Comment: Can you maybe expand the answer, explaining why -u is recommended in this context ?

Comment: set -u
Treat unset variables as an error, and immediately exit.