# make && echo "hello" only print hello when make succeeds (kernel)

Tags: kernel, compiling, make, c

For compiling the linux kernel, If I do

```
make_runner.sh && echo "hello"
```

it prints hello even if some of the kernel compilation fails.

Is there a way for it to only print if all of the compilation targets built correctly?

Where `make_runner.sh` is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -xe
make O=out ARCH=arm64 CC=clang CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- vendor/citrus-perf_defconfig
make O=out ARCH=arm64 CC=clang CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- -j$(nproc --all) 2>&1 | tee kernel.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the pipe to `tee`, the second `make`’s exit status is ignored.

To get the behaviour you want, you need to enable [`pipefail`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html): change the `set -xe` line to

```
set -xe -o pipefail
```

See [Debugging scripts, what is the difference between -x to set -euxo pipefail?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384305/86440) for details.